# how do I minimize my extension to windows taskbar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanna show my extension icon in taskbar like a hangouts extension. I searched a lot of things but I didn't found answer my question. Anyone can help me

Comment: As you can see in its manifest.json, it's using `system_indicator` which is [hardcoded in Chromium source code to Hangouts extension ids](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_manifest_features.json?l=224&rcl=65548a47). Google is great, isn't it? You can't use this feature in a public extension, but you can do it in a local personal one e.g. by copying `key` value from manifest.json of Hangouts to adopt its id.

Comment: Hmm, that source code link has another entry for "dev" so you may be able to use it in Chrome dev channel or Canary. Try copying the relevant code from Hangouts extensions by inspecting its files in the browser profile directory.